# Need an alternative to ProgressBar control for player resource pools (Health, etc.) in a game

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm trying to implement a basic Health/Stamina/Mana readout in a Windows Forms application, and my first approach was to use a ProgressBar control. However, I'm not fond of its visual representation in Aero (always green and too much distracting gloss animation), and I'm not quite ready to get into WPF development (which is, from what I can tell, the only way to modify it).

I also toyed with using a PictureBox control and sliding an image around horizontally, but it seemed like more trouble than it was worth.

Has anyone experimented with this and come up with a relatively simple solution? I'm just looking for a point in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I were you, instead of using a control, I will try to draw it myself.
Using GDI+ in WinForm is very easy, or you can use OpenGL/DirectX.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do some research on that stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There are a LOT of progress bars here:

[Code Project Progress Controls](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/)

and after checking out a few I think this could suit the Health/Stamina/Mana style
[Custom Progress](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/ProgBarPlus.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll check some out and see if they deal with the Aero visual issues. It really is the perfect control for this, aside from that.

Comment: If it turns out to be the answer. My question was regarding *alternatives* to the ProgressBar control; if one of these provides a ProgressBar control that eliminates the need for an alternative approach, then I'll consider it a valid answer.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted alternate Progress Bars to use instead of the included one...